# Getting error while obfuscating with Dasho jar java 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, obfuscation, java-17

```
Error: Error reading jar:file:/tmp/dasho-unwar49324873872.tmp/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-6.1.4.jar!/META-INF/versions/21/org/springframework/core/task/VirtualThreadDelegate.class:  Class Version Error.  Please recompile with a supported JDK or check for an update to DashO which supports the new version.
```

Using dasho version 12.2.0 and openjdk17 spring boot 3.2.2

Comment: The message indicates that Dasho doesn't support Java17.

Comment: The issue is Spring-core 6.1.x is a multi-release jar , it has a VirtualThreadDelegate.class for version 21 and Dasho does not support multi-release jar